# GridViewHelper is not recognised in VS 2010 when I use VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I have a gridview and I'd like to summarise data in it and I found some code to help me do that on the following website: http://www.agrinei.com/gridviewhelper/gridviewhelper_en.htm.

The thing is, when I tried to convert and use it in my program, GridViewHelper just refused to be recognised and so, now I'm stuck. Please let me know the right procedure to implement the same in VB. Thanks!

Comment: What error you are getting? I couldn't understand what you mean by "GridViewHelper just refused to be recognized"

Comment: @Anuraj, @yetanothercoder: The following is the code which I'd used and every single line is underlined and the error is either an "undefined" or "not a member" error. `Public Sub GridViewHelper(ByVal grd As GridView, ByVal useFooterForGeneralSummaries As Boolean, ByVal groupSortDirection As SortDirection)
Me.mGrid = grd
Me.useFooter = useFooterForGeneralSummaries
Me.groupSortDir = groupSortDirection
Me.mGeneralSummaries = New GridViewSummaryList()
Me.mGroups = New GridViewGroupList()
Me.mGrid.RowDataBound += New GridViewRowEventHandler(RowDataBoundHandler)
End Sub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the converter had some problem. Try rename the method

```
Public Sub GridViewHelper(ByVal grd As GridView, ByVal useFooterForGeneralSummaries As Boolean, ByVal groupSortDirection As SortDirection)
```

Like the following

```
Public Sub New(ByVal grd As GridView, ByVal useFooterForGeneralSummaries As Boolean, ByVal groupSortDirection As SortDirection)
```

Because the constructor in C# is the class name itself, but in VB.Net its new only.

Comment: Changed your username eh? The converter did say New, but when that didn't work, I tried GridViewHelper and that's not working either. Nothing is. What to do?

Comment: I didn't converted it. But everything looks okay to me.

Comment: Then what could be the problem? Should I add a reference or something?

Comment: I don't think. Please verify Namespace / Class / Methods are in correct place. Also make sure all the member variables exists.

Comment: Will do and let you know. Thanks!:)